# Laravel status not found, missing route

Tags: laravel-4, vhosts

I'm trying to install Laravel on Wamp server and I'm getting this error:

```
{"status":"Not Found","error":true,"error_code":"missing_route","message":"Route not found.","data":[]}
```

Been searching for a while now and can't figure out what it is. I checked and triple checked if I added corectly my project in hosts file, if virtual host is set properly, also if rewrite module is activated and if .htaccess file in the public folder is as it should.

**Hosts File:**

```
127.0.0.1   app.my-site.com
```

**Vhosts**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@my-site.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/my-site/public"
    ServerName app.my-site.com
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/my-site/public">
       AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/my-site-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/my-site-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess in public folder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anybody suggest what could be wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you doing when that error occurs? It seems that you already have Laravel installed so it's unclear what leads to that error.

Comment: I'm just visiting app.my-site.com

Comment: Try doing a `php artisan cache:clear`, `composer dumpautoload` and then `php artisan routes`. Do you see that route in the list ?